# Get current revision number in Subclipse?

Tags: eclipse, subclipse

While normally I use the Subversive plugin (Eclipse) for SVN, I've decided to try Subclipse, which seems to be more popular and better documented.

Something I've taken for granted from Subversive is the current revision number shown. With Subversive, this is shown very clearly next to the menu:

```
MyProject 43 [https://code.google.com...]
```

Subversive is a bit different and the revision number is nowhere to be seen:

```
MyProject [foo/trunk]
```

How can I get the revision number to be shown in Subclipse? It's something I've come to rely on..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just downloaded and installed the latest Subclipse 1.6.2 in my Galileo eclipse3.5RC4.

In "`Windows > Preferences > Team > SVN > Label decorations`":

Tab "Text"

Add `{revision}` to the "Project Format" line:

```
{dirty_flag}{name} {revision} [{url_short}]
```

That would get the project to be displayed *exactly* as:

```
MyProject 43 [https://code.google.com...]
```

See also this [help page](http://help.collab.net/index.jsp?topic=/org.tigris.subclipse.doc/topics/preferences.html), although the latest 1.6.2 plugin has changed a bit its preferences display:

[image: http://help.collab.net/topic/org.tigris.subclipse.doc/images/screenshots/preferences-svn-dec-text.png]