# How to add file revision (not the last changed revision) to Subclipse "Label decorations"?

Tags: eclipse, svn, version-control, subclipse

Firstly, please beware I'm new to SVN.

Then, my question has much in common with [Get current revision number in Subclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973788/get-current-revision-number-in-subclipse).

The (seeming) problem is (I use Ecpilse v3.5.0 (build id I20090611-1540)):

1. My freshly installed Subclipse plugin offers `"revision - last revision loaded into workspace"` label under `"Windows > Preferences > Team > SVN > Label decorations"`
2. That seems to correspond to `"Last changed revision"` under `"File > Properties > Subversion"` (and not the `"Revision"` there).

Hence, the question.

Answer (score 1):

Revision number you see when adding {revision} to the file label decoration (which is there by default) is revision of repository in which this file (either its contents or properties) was last time changed.

Note, that there are no such thing in Subversion as "revision of a file", instead there is revisions of the whole repository in which one or more files have been changed.